# Match exact phrase and words in regex

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm splitting a search result string so I can use [Rails Highlight](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper/highlight) to highlight the terms. In some cases, there will be exact matches **and** single words in the same search term and I'm trying to write regex that will do that in a single pass.

```
search_term = 'pizza cheese "ham and pineapple" pepperoni'

search_term.split(/\W+/)
=> ["pizza", "cheese", "ham", "and", "pineapple", "pepperoni"]

search_term.split(/(?=\")\W+/)
=> ["pizza cheese ", "ham and pineapple", "pepperoni"]
```

I can get `ham and pineapple` on its own (without the unwanted quotes), and I can easily split all the words, but is there some regex that will return an array like:

```
search_term.split(‍♂️)
=> ["pizza", "cheese", "ham and pineapple", "pepperoni"]
```

Comment: Why not [use `CSV.Parse`](https://ideone.com/ce6a5J)?

Comment: Another regex solution: [`.scan(/[^"\s]+|"\s*\K[^"]+/)`](https://ideone.com/cTgu5L)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes:

```
/"[^"]*?"|\w+/
```

https://regex101.com/r/fzHI4g/2

Not done as a split.  Just take stuff in quotes, or single words...each one is a match.

```
£ cat pizza
pizza "a and b" pie
£ ruby -ne 'print $_.scan(/"[^"]*?"|\w+/)' pizza
["pizza", "\"a and b\"", "pie"]
£
```

so...`search_term.scan(/regex/)` seems to return the array you want.

To exclude the quotes you need:
This puts the quotes in lookarounds which assert that the matched expression has a quote before it (lookbehind), and a quote after it (lookahead) rather than containing the quotes.

```
/(?<=")\w[^"]*?(?=")|\w+/
```

Note that because the last regex doesn't consume the quotes, it uses whitespace to determine beginning vs. ending quotes so `" a bear"` is not ok.  This can be solved with capture groups, but if this is an issue, like I said in the comments, I would recommend just trimming quotes off each array element and using the regex at the top of the answer.

Comment: Works except for the `g` option.

Comment: @SebastianPalma - Thanks, looks like `/g` is the default in Ruby.

Comment: For the split to work I need this to be inverted. Rather than matching the words, I need to match the non-words -- the white space and the quotes, but I need to ignore the white space between quotes.

Comment: That's why you shouldn't do a split.  Makes the regex insanely complicated.

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to exclude the escaped quotes in the returned array? `["pizza", "a and b"]` rather than `["pizza", "\"a and b\""]`?

Comment: @BHOLT - See updated regex at bottom.  I had to change it because not consuming the quotes caused problems.  This updated regex requires whitespace before and after quoted expressions, and requires NO whitespace after opening quotes.  I'd actually just recommend using the original one and stripping off quotes.

Answer (score 1):

```
r = /
    (?<=\") # match a double quote in a positive lookbehind
    (?!\s)  # next char cannot be a whitespace, negative lookahead
    [^"]+   # match one or more characters other than double-quote  
    (?<!\s) # previous char cannot be a whitespace, negative lookbehind
    (?=\")  # match a double quote in a positive lookahead
    |       # or
    \w+     # match one or more word characters
    /x      # free-spacing regex definition mode

str = 'pizza "ham and pineapple" mushroom pepperoni "sausage and anchovies"'

str.scan r
  #=> ["pizza", "ham and pineapple", "mushroom", "pepperoni",
  #    "sausage and anchovies"]
```

Comment: breaks with input `pizza cheese "ham and pineapple" mushroom pepperoni "sausage and anchovies"` (same issue I ran into above)

Comment: PS--If we instead use `/"([^"]*?)"|(\w+)/`, the quotes are now consumed, and the regex behaves correctly again, with the data we want in either capture group 1 or 2.  https://regex101.com/r/fzHI4g/3  But I have no idea how to extract capture group data in Ruby.

Comment: @zzxyz, good point. I understand the problem.  Re your suggestion, `a = str.scan /"([^"]*?)"|(\w+)/ #=> [[nil, "pizza"], ["ham and pineapple", nil], [nil, "mushroom"], [nil, "pepperoni"], ["sausage and anchovies", nil]]`, so we could write `a.flat_map(&:compact) #=> ["pizza", "ham and pineapple", "mushroom", "pepperoni", "sausage and anchovies"]`, but that's pretty ugly. I did an edit but not happy about that either.

Comment: I like the `flat_map` solution a lot, myself.  I ended up figuring out `.flatten.select`, but that's better, and I think they both beat gnarly regexes or having to trim quotes off the results